# Launch a new activity from notification bar when that same activity is currently being used

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I launch a specific Activity from a button in notification. If I'm not currently opening that specific Activity, it will launch the Activity as a new one. However, when I'm opening that specific Activity, scroll down the notification then click that button, it would do nothing as the Activity already opened. I need to open it as a new one as new values will be passed into it. I **could** use SharedPreferences to do that but I prefer not to. Please help

```
        intent = new Intent(context,AppReport.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",packageInstallName); //this does not get send over
        intent.putExtra("version",packageInstallVersion);
        PendingIntent testing = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        setOnClickPendingIntent(buttons[1],testing);
```

This is how the activity is launched from notification bar. I tried FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT for the flag but also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Activity as `singleTop`

```
<activity
        android:name=".AppReport"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

intent = new Intent(context,AppReport.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",packageInstallName); //this does not get send over
    intent.putExtra("version",packageInstallVersion);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent testing = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Override `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` in Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: No need for 'launchMode=singleTask', the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP would make the 'onNewIntent' be called. Also I believe it should be 'launchMode=singleTop' in order for the 'onNewIntent' to be called... Apart from that nice example :)

Comment: Yeah `singleTop` will also do the trick they are in same Task already . Thx

Comment: Thanks! I had a little more trouble with the activity calling onResume and retrieved previous values instead of new ones, setIntent(intent); in onNewIntent solved that.